# Google Cloud AutoML Vision: Compute Region configuration not being recognized

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automl, google-cloud-automl

I have set my compute region and zone to `us-east4` using Google Cloud SDK

`$ gcloud init`

`$ gcloud config set compute/region us-east4`

`$ gcloud config set compute/zone us-east4`

however the AutoML Vision model keeps defaulting to `us-central1`. I have tried restarting terminal and training a new model after confirming that my compute region is set to `us-east4` and the project/account are correct.

---

```
$ gcloud config configurations list

NAME         IS_ACTIVE  ACCOUNT                  PROJECT                     DEFAULT_ZONE  DEFAULT_REGION
default      True       xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com  xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  us-east4-b    us-east4
```

---

When I request a prediction in Python with my compute region argument set to `us-east4` I get an error saying:

```
400 List of found errors: 1.Field: name; Message: The provided location ID is not valid. : InvalidArgument
```

However when I request a prediction with the compute region argument set to `us-central1` it works and I get a prediction response. I am not sure why this is or if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Prerequisite #10 here: [AutoML Vision API Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/tutorial). It says:

> "AutoML Vision currently requires the location us-central1"

Note that [Cloud AutoML](https://cloud.google.com/automl/) stills on Beta so it might take a while before it gets available in other locations. So, for now, you won't be able to change it.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for the info!